# Is is possible to set a session variable in Application.cfc and then retrieve it from any of the application pages?

Tags: session, coldfusion, application.cfc

**With the example I have provided I would like for the index.cfm to display `hello`
How can I do this?**

Application.cfc

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cfset this.sessionManagement = true /> 

    <cffunction name="onSessionStart">
        <cfset SESSION.myVar = "hello">
    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

index.cfm

```
<html>
    <head>

    <title>Testing</title>

    </head>

    <body>
        <cfoutput>#SESSION.myVar#</cfoutput>
    </body>
</html>
```

<strike>I have discovered that when I add</strike>

```
<cfinvoke component="Application" method="onSessionStart">
```

to the index.cfm it works, however all the variable gets overridden every time the page is refreshed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to give your application a name, eg:

```
<cfset this.name = "foo">
```

In your Application.cfc pseudo-constructor.  Otherwise CF can't create an application, and so it cannot associate the session with the application.

Comment: duh. can't believe i missed that. +1

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that you're new to  ColdFusion or at least Application.cfc, but yes, onSessionStart is the basic way to initiate Session variables in your Application. Of course, they can be set/deleted/reset in any other page, so it might be good pratice to check for the existence of the variable in the SESSION scope before outputting it:

```
<cfif StructKeyExists(SESSION, "myVar")>
    <cfoutput>#SESSION.myVar#</cfoutput>
</cfif>
```

If the variable is not persisting, have you checked your Session Timeout setting (in ColdFusion Administrator)? You can set it there, which sets a default for all applications on the server, or you can set it right in Application.cfc:

```
THIS.SessionTimeout = CreateTimeSpan(0, 1, 0, 0); // One hour Session Timeout
```

Comment: +1 for the caveat on checking that variables are defined on every page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can set variables in onSessionStart and use them in the application. The onSessionStart function only fires when a new session is created, so if it is being called on every request then your sessions are not persisting (your CFID / CFTOKEN, JSESSIONID) is not being passed on to subsequent requests. This is probably due to cookies being disabled.

Comment: I was having onSessionStart being called on every request due to a slightly different reason.  My application.cfc extended from ColdBox, but I had a bootstrapped separate ColdBox instance running as well (copy/paste error).  So, sometimes it can happen even if the session info is being passed back.